# use of parseInt

Tags: java, arrays, parseint

I want to use parseInt() method, but I don't now how to put array a
my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StaticMethodsWrapper {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = input.nextInt();
    int[] a = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        a[i] = input.nextInt();
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
        System.out.println(a[i]);

    int x = Integer.parseInt(a);//here is the error
}
}
```

Comment: Not sure what you're asking.  a is already an integer array.

Comment: I want to make it as a number exampe: if I enter elements:5 6 7 I want to gat them as a number like:567

Comment: Why do you have to parseInt() it if you've already put it in the a array??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`parseInt(a)` expects `String` type parameter for `a`. But you are providing it with `int[]` parameter. It is an array not a string.

If you want to concatenate all numbers use this code when you have your `a` array populated:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (int oneInt:a) {
  sb.append(oneInt);
}

System.out.println(sb.toString);
```

And later you can parse this composed string to `int` or `long` variable type via `parseInt` of `Integer` class or `parseLong` of `Long` class. Like that:

```
long myLong = Long.parseInt(sb.toString());
```